# Puzzling sentence at end of quote

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

I really don’t get the meaning of the last sentence of this quote:

> So so beautiful! You get, I’m sure, how amazing it is that she *allowed* it in the end? My mother never would have. **I think she must have gotten how much it gave *you* for her to receive!**

<sup>([Comment on Iva Izabela's answer](https://www.quora.com/What-made-you-happy-today/answer/Iva-Izabela?share=68cdf31e&srid=hnyk7), italics in original)</sup>

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained more about what is confusing you.

Answer (score 2):

It can be rewritten

> She must have understood how much you appreciated the chance to give her something.

"to get" = [to understand, to comprehend](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get#british-1-1-11)<sub>Cambridge Dictionary</sub>